# Conditional Formatting Autofill on Google Sheets for Variable condition

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting, autofill

*I've looked in quite a few places here and I can't find a solution specific to my problem so i've made an account to ask it.*

**In Google Sheets, I have made a sheet to announce winners of a sports match, like:**

Player1 | Player2 | player1score | player2score

Player3 | Player4 | player3score | player4score

Player5 | Player6 | player5score | player6score

etc.

What I have done is if **player1score** is larger than **player2score**, then **Player1** is highlighted green, and if the opposite is true, its highlighted red, and vice versa for **Player 2**, using conditional formatting of: **=player1score>player2score** for green and **=player2score>player1score** for red. (with the cell IDs)

I have about 100 odd rows of this, and I want to drag down and autofill for all the other players in the sheet, but when I do this, it applies the conditional formatting for, say, Player5 in comparison to player1score and player2score instead of player5score and player6score, as the values of the custom formula aren't incrementing

Is there a way I can auto increment it without having to write them all in manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yellow:

```
=($C2=$D2)*(C2<>"")
```

green:

```
=(C2=MAX($C2:$D2))*($C2<>"")
```

red:

```
=(C2=MIN($C2:$D2))*($C2<>"")
```

[image]

[image]

note the range A2:B or C2:D

**[here's the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jHdpYAD-5r1eWiCu69QWO4BbkofshHw_1kBg07p6G5w/edit#gid=738909429)**

Comment: Wow thanks that works just as I intended! I understand the range now, but I don't quite understand the end of the formula, *($C2<>"") , what exactly does that do?

Comment: @KutKommTom it assures empty rows won't get formated